# Use UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal in a UIPopoverController

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am trying to present a modal view controller inside a UIPopOver.
I have set :
 `[theViewController setModalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationCurrentContext]`; so as to allow the transition within the pop over and not outside the pop over.

The problem here is that I am getting error message:
  "`Application tried to present inside popover with transition style other than UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical`",
if I am setting :
 `[theViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal]`.

I want to have the 'flip horizontal' type animation within the popover when I modally present the view controller instead of the default. How can I achieve this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Good question but the bottom line is you cannot do it - Apple only lets you do it one way now.